# How can I change rubberband colour on Desktop?

Tags: gnome, themes, 21.10, zsh, css

(Sorry for any bad English)

Lately, I have been customizing my system (Ubuntu 21.10 themed with Yaru Dark and Zsh as shell with powerlevel10k theme). I set it all up, including a cool colour palette. **Here is my problem: when I left click on the Desktop and drag, the rubberband generated appears orange, the default colour, which broke the aesthetics of the palette I choose.**

[image: 1]

**What I want to do is change the colour of the rubberband**

At first, I only managed to figure out how to change the colour of the cursor highlighting when pressing Ctrl key, and it didn't even work for me!

Then I tried editing

`/usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

and also

`/usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gtk-4.0/gtk.css`.

But both files only had one line:

`@import url("resource:///com/ubuntu/themes/Yaru-dark/3.0/gtk.css");`.

I tried by adding the code:

```
XfdesktopIconView.view .rubberband, .content-view rubberband, treeview.view rubberband, flowbox rubberband,
rubberband,
.rubberband {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

But for my bad luck, nothing happened...

If you know how to change the colour, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below lines in the file `/usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gtk-3.20/gtk.css` for testing purpose. Once it is satisfactory create a local theme so that, the changes will not be overwritten when packages are updated.

```
.view:selected:focus, .view:selected, .view text:selected:focus {
  background-color: orange; }
```

Change the color "orange" with any other color you wish in above line.

Tested in Ubuntu 21.10 with "Yaru-dark" theme.

[image]

Comment: It finally worked, thank you!